# postfix restrict mail relay for certain sender addresses ("MAIL FROM:") only

Tags: postfix

I'd like to configure postfix to relay mail from certain sender addresses only. Postfix should relay mail to different relayhosts(/smarthosts) (Gmail, AOL, ...) dependent on the sender's address ("MAIL FROM:").

So far, my current configuration works as follows:

- Users authenticate on postfix for mail relay in general. If they cannot authenticate, no relay is possible. Note that this authentication is different from the authentication for the relayhosts.
- Dependent on the sender's address ("MAIL FROM:"), a certain relayhost is selected (`smtp_sender_dependent_authentication`, `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`, `smtp_sasl_password_maps`). This also works fine.
- However, if the user can authenticate, and has a sender address not covered in `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`, postfix tries to directly relay the mail - which often does not work due to IP address restrictions (blacklists).

---

My question is now: how to reject mail that would have been relayed directly (without smarthost), i.e., where the sender's address is not listed in `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`? Any hints how to achieve this?

Comment: What shows the log?, you can configure it to show more verbose output. In master.cf file append one or more -v options to selected daemon and execute command postfix reload. smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -v

Comment: The log show that it is working as described: If the sender's address matches an address in the `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`, then the log shows `maps_find: smtp_sasl_password_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.hash: ADDRESS = USER:PASS`. Otherwise, a direct connection is established, but the relay is rejected from the smarthost: `refused to talk to me: SMARTHOST ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554-IP address is black listed`

Comment: Currently, there are no technical problem with postfix. What I'm looking for is some hint how to change the configuration in order to get in a new 'feature' - namely rejecting mail for relay with an unknown sender's address (i.e., which is not listed in `smtp_sasl_password_maps`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need some limiting test **before** `permit_sasl_authenticated`. A prerequisite for this would be having separated smtpd on port `25` for incoming mail and another smtpd for *submission* on port `587`. Otherwise this limitation would cause incoming mail to be rejected as it won't pass the test. Then, remove the `permit_sasl_authenticated` from the port `25` altogether, and add the test to your submission configuration in `master.cf`.

- To answer your question literally, [`check_sender_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) would be a suitable test, whitelisting all the domains listed in `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` and rejecting mail for the rest.

  > `check_sender_access type:table`
  >
  > Search the specified [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) database for the `MAIL FROM` address,
  >   domain, parent domains, or `localpart@`, and execute the corresponding
  >   action.

  This can be added to either [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) or [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_access).
- What would do the same, but further prevent users from using each other's addresses is using [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch). This needs an additional [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) table, but if your `virtual_alias_maps` entries are already formed as `address@example.com username`, you can use the same file and the allowed sender addresses are automatically updated whenever you update your virtual aliases database with `postmap`. An example of such submission configuration in the `master.cf`:

  ```
  submission inet n - - - - smtpd
  # Other parameters
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  # Other parameters
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read some further documentation, and found [reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) - wouldn't that do all the stuff you mentioned in your answer (allowing incoming mail, submission of mail/for relay from authenticated users only and to specfied relayhosts only), but without having to open a submission port? The restriction should be put before `permit_sasl_authenticated` on the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` parameter. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Nicely spotted! If you wish to use port `25` for both, `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` is your choice. Using different port for submission has some advantages: you can have totally different set of settings for authenticated users, and avoid the limitations for port `25` in many consumer grade internet connections.